# Getting parent element in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events

I have tried to get the parent element's id of the clicked element. I have tried this

```
$(window).click(function(event) {
    alert("Clicked on " + event.target.id + ". Its parent is " + $(event.target).parent().attr("id"));
});
```

If I have the following structure, it returns `Clicked on x. Its parent is undefined`.

```
<div id="y">
    <div id="x">X</div>
</div>
```

Why isn't it giving the parent's id?

I have tried the following too

```
$(this).closest("div").attr("id");
$(this).parent().attr('id')
```

Comment: [Your code](http://jsfiddle.net/cAeRA/). Gives `Its parent is y`, when I try it.

Comment: It works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/5AM2Y/ (If you click somewhere other than on X it says "Clicked on . Its parent is undefined")

Comment: I created a fiddle. http://fiddle.jshell.net/Jg3mX/  It works just fine? What jquery version + browser are you using?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Not sure why, but my browser had stored an old copy of the Javascript file and used it. I had non working code in the previous one. The snippet in the original post works ok.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).on('click', '.clicked-element', function(){
    parentElId = $(this).parent().attr('id');
   // parentElId = $(this).parents('.custom-parent-class').attr('id'); // if you wan't the id from a different parent
});
```

Comment: Regardless of whether this works, why would the OP's code not work? (Given that it _does_ work for us.)

Answer (score 0):

You probably use before() function of jquery

```
<div class="container">
  <h2>Greetings</h2>
  <div class="inner">Hello</div>
  <div class="inner">Goodbye</div>
</div> 

$('.inner').before('<p>Test</p>');
```

Output:

```
<div class="container">
  <h2>Greetings</h2>
  <div class="inner">Hello</div>
  <p>Test</p>
  <div class="inner">Goodbye</div>
</div>
```

Here is detail link for that function http://api.jquery.com/before/

Answer (score -1):

As I think:

```
 $(event.target).parent().attr("id");
```

Comment: what exactly you offering to change?

Comment: to use event.target and parent at the same place, not this and not closest(). I thought it is clear. It is working and I do not understand with -1